# Regex - Conditional replace if captured group exists

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Suppose I have the following 2 strings representing phone numbers:

1. 1112223333
2. 11122233334

The first one is for a normal phone number `(111) 222-3333` and the second one is for a phone number with an extension `(111) 222-3333 ext 4`

So we know the phone number will always be 10 digits and possibly 11. If it is 11, then I'd like it formatted with the second version.

My current regex and replace are as follows:

**Regex:** `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d?)`

**Replacement:** `($1) $2-$3 ext $4`

Which works, except that regardless whether the 4th capturing group exists or not, I get the "ext" added in, so I get:

1. `1112223333`  > `(111) 222-3333 ext` (should be `(111) 222-3333` (no "ext" suffix)
2. `11122233334` > `(111) 222-3333 ext 4` (correct)

I know I can do this via code / evaluating matches (I'm programming in C# / .Net), but I'm more curious to know *if there a way to change the replacement regex itself* to have some form of logic to only add the suffix `ext $4` if and only if there was a 4th capturing group?

Comment: What is the programming language/tool? Not every regex can do that directly in the replacement pattern, but almost each language has a callback method support in the regex replacement method.

Comment: You can use [If-Then-Else Conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Comment: @MarounMaroun, could you show me how? I've been trying and don't know how to put that into the replacement.

Comment: @JohnBustos I think that really depends on the language/tool you're using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm programming in C# / .Net, but, again, I know I can do it via code, I'm more asking out of curiosity to see if / how I could use only the regex engine.

Comment: @JohnBustos regex engine doesn't replace, it only *matches*. Replacement is part of the language/tool features.

Comment: In .NET, you do not have a conditional replacement pattern support. Use a callback inside `Regex.Replace`. Sorry, but this is the right answer.

Comment: ... I was afraid of that, @WiktorStribiżew... Darn it!! :/

Comment: Check if you can install Boost library for .NET. Then, you could do that. Or PCRE2 (the latest builds). Note that Notepad++ can do that :) Try `(?<f>\d{3})(?<s>\d{3})(?<t>\d{4})(?<e>\d)?` -> `(?{e}\($+{f}\) $+{s}-$+{t} ext $+{e}:\($+{f}\) $+{s}-$+{t})`

Comment: Or just [do two replaces](http://ideone.com/hYiT61): `string txt = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(phone, @"(^\d{10})(\d)", "$1 ext $2"), @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");`

Comment: @bobblebubble, also a good idea - Just sucks the .Net Regex engine itself doesn't let you deal with captures conditionally... Not to say it's not freaking awesome as-is :)

Comment: @Maroun If-Then-Else Conditionals wouldn't help in this situation.  As you said the engine only matches, and since the word 'ext' doesn't appear in the string, the engine can't add it.  The best you could do is:

Regex: (\d{3})(\d{3})((?(?=\d{5})\d{5}|\d{4}))
Replacement: \($1\) $2-$3

which is just a more complicated version of what the OP posted. If I'm wrong please let me know and post a solution.  I'd like to know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I just found something interesting.  
https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplaceconditional.html

For the replacement side of the engine, there does seem to be a way to do what the OP intended:

\($1\) $2-$3 ${4:+ext $4}

I verified this at regex101.com but it only worked in PCRE2 but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the nearest I could get to this is using the match evaluator overload with C# 6 string interpolation.

Sample using C# 6 string interpolation:

```
var phone = "01234567894";
var txt = Regex.Replace(
    phone,
    @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d?)$",
    m => $"({m.Groups[1]}) {m.Groups[2]}-{m.Groups[3]}{(m.Groups[4].Success ? " ext " + m.Groups[4].Value : "")}");
```

Or, if using older C#, using `String.Format`:

```
var phone = "01234567894";
var txt = Regex.Replace(
    phone,
    @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d?)$",
    m => String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}{3}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3],
        m.Groups[4].Success ? " ext " + m.Groups[4].Value : ""));
```

Comment: Thanks, Miguel. I did a very similar thing in my C# program, I was more hoping to see if it was at all possible to use the regex engine itself rather than via code, but thank you so much for your time and work on this!

Comment: Unfortunately the docs don't mention anything like what you wanted: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And this is how it should be done for now with the default Regex class.